# Trying to make URL Rewrite in HtAccess to clean folder names

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am actually trying to put an .htaccess file to have the "virtual" folder /evenement/ to point to /evenements-futur.php.

Here is what I have actually:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /evenement$ /evenements-futur.php [L]
```

I know im not that far from the "Final Answer"...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 404 Error. /evenement not found

Comment: I tried with a page itself that i took from an Online Tutorial and it is working so I know that mod_rewrite is on on the server

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on superuser.com

Comment: Are you running from a sub-directory (as compared to your document root)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are adding the rule to your .htaccess file in your site's root directory. If yes, you just need to ditch the leading `/` as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^evenement/?$ /evenements-futur.php [L]
```

The `/?` makes sure the rule works for both `domain.com/evenement` and with the terminating `/` as `domain.com/evenement/`.